# How to disabeld today date in Calendar.setup magento?

Tags: magento

How to disable today current date after 5pm in  Calendar.setup magento?
please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
             $a = $.noConflict();
           $a(function () {

                var date = new Date();
                var currHour = date.getHours();
                if(currHour >= 17){
                    var nextDate = (date.getDate() + 1)+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getYear(); 
                    $a("#date").datepicker({minDate : 1, dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
                }else{
                    $a("#date").datepicker({minDate : 0, dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
                }
            });
            function time_change(){
                var date_of = document.getElementById('date').value;
                var d = new Date(date_of);
                var day = d.getDate();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var dt = new Date();
                var currDay = parseInt(dt.getDate());
                var time = parseInt(dt.getHours());
                if(day > currDay){
                    options ='<option value="11:00">11 AM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="12:00">12 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="13:00">01 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="14:00">02 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="15:00">03 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="16:00">04 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="17:00">05 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="18:00">06 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="19:00">07 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="20:00">08 PM</option>';
                    jQuery("#delivery_instruction").html(options);
                }
                else if(time >= 8 && time < 17){
                    var hour = time+3;
                    var options="";
                    while(hour<=20){
                        if(hour>=13){
                            if(hour==13)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">01 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==14)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">02 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==15)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">03 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==16)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">04 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==17)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">05 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==18)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">06 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==19)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">07 PM</option>';
                            if(hour==20)
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">08 PM</option>';


                        }else{
                            if(hour<=12){
                                options +='<option value="'+hour+':00">'+hour+' PM</option>';

                            }
                        }
                        hour++;
                    }
                    jQuery("#delivery_instruction").html(options);

                }else if(time >= 17){
                    options ='<option value="11:00">11 AM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="12:00">12 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="13:00">01 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="14:00">02 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="15:00">03 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="16:00">04 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="17:00">05 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="18:00">06 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="19:00">07 PM</option>';
                    options +='<option value="20:00">08 PM</option>';
                    jQuery("#delivery_instruction").html(options);
                }
            }
          </script>
          <input type="text" name="date"  onchange="time_change()" class="input-text required-entry" id="date">
          <select name="delivery_instruction" id="delivery_instruction" class="input-text required-entry getTime"></select>
```

working fine http://darktemptations.in/

Answer (score 0):

As part of the calendar setup you can define disabled days with the disableFunc option.  The below will disable all dates prior to today's date, so all you need to is check whether 5pm has passed, and add 1 day to the now variable.  Don't forget javascript uses a zero index for date fields, so the time 17:00 would be hour 16, eg;

```
Calendar.setup({
                    inputField : 'deliverydate',
                    ifFormat : '%d-%m-%Y',
                    button : 'cal_image',
                    align : 'Bl',
                    singleClick : true,
                    disableFunc : function(date) {
                       var now = new Date();
                       if(now.getHours() > 16) { now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1); }
                if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
                if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
                if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate())  { return true; } }
                 }
                 });
```

Comment: I tried code but not working coming error  hilite day undefined hilite selected

Comment: can yuo update your question with exactly what you've got so far.